# Launching Selenium tests from phpunit.xml

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm launching tests from phpunit.xml file in PHPStorm. I added sample Selenium test to the tests suite.

Test class source code:

```
class GitHubTest extends sdGenericTestCase {

  /**
   * @var \RemoteWebDriver
   */
  protected $webDriver;

  public function setUp()
  {
    $capabilities = array(WebDriverCapabilityType::BROWSER_NAME => 'firefox');
    $this->webDriver = RemoteWebDriver::create('http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub', $capabilities);
  }

  protected $url = 'https://github.com';

  public function testGitHubHome()
  {
    $this->webDriver->get($this->url);
    // checking that page title contains word 'GitHub'
    $this->assertContains('GitHub', $this->webDriver->getTitle());

  }

}
```

I've got following error:

Fatal error: Class 'WebDriverCapabilityType' not found in

Library exists in the system, this class is located in:

> /usr/share/php/facebook/webdriver/lib/remote/WebDriverCapabilityType.php

but isn't autoloaded.

What should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like a PHPStorm configuration or phpunit config issue, rather than selenium/webdriver/php.
Are your tests working when launched from command line via phpunit?

Did you set-up your 'Path to script', 'Default configuration file' and 'Default bootstrap file' under Run -> Edit Configurations -> Default -> PhpUnit or a 'Custom working directory' (that automatically reads the files from that dir) ?